# iPhone 4s switches back on immediately after switching off?

Tags: iphone, shutdown, damage

I dropped my iPhone 4S in a puddle.

After a few days in rice everything was fine, except the battery life sucks and as soon as I power the phone off (completely) the apple logo appears and it turns on once again.

This means that I cannot replace the battery as the phone must be off to replace it.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: If memory serves, iPhone 4S opens from the back, so theoretically you *could* just take off the back cover and unplug  the battery even with the phone on. Im pretty sure I've done this a few times in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me once, after I got the charging port wet on my iPhone 4s.

I was able to power down my iPhone by having it connected to a power source while going through the shutdown sequence. It would then remain off even if I unplugged the cable.

Of course you could simply let it drain all the way down, especially if battery life is as awful as you say.